# Would Hogwarts' Quidditch teams accept students from different houses?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, quidditch

I wanted to know, would it be against Hogwarts school rules to allow, say, a Slytherin to join the Hufflepuff Quidditch team? I don't recall anything saying so, or any statements from J.K. Rowling.

Comment: It wouldn’t really be a Hufflepuff team if they let people from other houses on, would it? So presumably no. But I don’t recall seeing anything specifically saying so either.

Comment: Well one thing is certain: even if it was allowed (and Miss Bella feels it's against rules and I imagine it is - and it would also cause house cup problems) there wouldn't be a Slytherin at all with Gryffindor and vice versa. Even other houses want Gryffindor to win if it means Slytherin doesn't!

Comment: The Hogwarts house system is not something Rowling invented out of thin air, it's very directly based on the way British boarding-schools work.  In real life, inter-house sports/competition teams are limited to members of that house.  The question might not have even occurred to Rowling (it certainly didn't occur to me, and I _went_ to boarding school for a bit, and took part in house competitions).  So, I'd absolutely expect not - however, if you asked Rowling about it, she'd likely make up something on the spot based on what was the most interesting answer. :)

Comment: @cloudfeet Agreed - I *didn't* go to a boarding school, but we still had houses/forms and intra-school competition.  This question's a bit like asking "Could a Durmstrang student have entered the Triwizard Tournament as the Hogwarts champion?"

Comment: Welcome to the site, by the way. I hope you stick around.

Comment: This makes no more sense than asking why a French person can't compete for Germany in the Olympics.

Comment: @DJClayworth lots of athletes do that, in order to be able to take part in the competition.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear you're supposed to play for your house's team--probably if your parents are big donors or something, you can transfer to and play for whatever house you want.

Comment: Note: the examples of sports that allow people from outside (institution/region) to participate on (institution/region)'s team are mostly professional sports. The model here (for a U.S. person, like me) would be more like high school or college sports, where people who aren't enrolled in the institution are normally not allowed to be on the institution's team.

Comment: @Chronocidal I don't know about that. Not quite. Because the Goblet of Fire is a bit - I'm not even sure how to put it other than to say it's binding magically whereas I don't believe Quidditch is. On the other hand though it could be manipulated as happens to Harry... True you say 'a bit like' but it's also a bit different.

Comment: This does seem a bit like a Mississippi State University student playing for the University of Mississippi team.

Answer (score 50):

## It’s probably against the rules, and certainly very atypical.

Professor McGonagall tells students that they can sign up for *their* house team by asking their Head of House to put them down for tryouts. She doesn’t say anything about playing for another’s.

> “Those wishing to play **for their house** Quidditch teams should give their names to their Heads of House as usual. We are also looking for new Quidditch commentators, who should do likewise.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 8 (Snape Victorious)*</sup></sub>

When Harry directs Quidditch tryouts, students who aren’t from Gryffindor show up, and Harry made them all leave. He didn’t allow them to try out. If they were supposed to be able to try out for another house’s team, then Harry wouldn’t be allowed to make them all leave before they could.

> “The third group had a pile-up halfway around the pitch. Most of the fourth group had come without broomsticks. The fifth group were Hufflepuffs.
>
> ‘If there’s anyone else here who’s not from Gryffindor,’ roared Harry, who was starting to get seriously annoyed, ‘leave now, please!’
>
> There was a pause, then a couple of little Ravenclaws went sprinting off the pitch, snorting with laughter.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 11 (Hermione’s Helping Hand)*</sup></sub>

It doesn’t seem like something that would be typically allowed. Students are usually loyal to their house, so most wouldn’t even want to play for another house. In addition, if students were allowed to play for another house, they could use this to cheat for *their* house. For example, a Ravenclaw could play for the Hufflepuff team and purposely not play well in matches against Ravenclaw, making sure that Ravenclaw gets more house points and does better in the Quidditch Cup. Even if they don’t purposely sabotage anything, they’d be less likely to ‘give their all’ against their own house (consciously or not) since they wouldn’t want to see their house lose.

If they were somehow able to play in a completely unbiased way, and not even subconsciously ‘taking it easy’ on their own house’s team, they’d still have to contend with both the team they’re on doubting their true allegiance. Cormac McLaggen accused Ginny of giving Ron an easy save because he’s her brother, which Harry says wasn’t true.

> “His sister didn’t really try,’ said McLaggen menacingly. There was a vein pulsing in his temple like the one Harry had often admired in Uncle Vernon’s. ‘She gave him an easy save.’
>
> ‘Rubbish,’ said Harry coldly. ‘That was the one he nearly missed.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 11 (Hermione’s Helping Hand)*</sup></sub>

If someone was allowed to join another house’s team, if they ever did anything that caused their own house to have an advantage (whether or not it was actually intentional or just a mistake) they’d have to deal with the other team members accusing them of throwing it purposefully for their house. People even get upset if *other* houses lose points if it means a house they dislike will win instead.

> “And then the story started to spread: Harry Potter, the famous Harry Potter, their hero of two Quidditch matches, had lost them all those points, him and a couple of other stupid first-years.
>
> From being one of the most popular and admired people at the school, Harry was suddenly the most hated. Even Ravenclaws and Hufflepuffs turned on him, because everyone had been longing to see Slytherin lose the House Cup.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 15 (The Forbidden Forest)*</sup></sub>

It'd also cause problems with figuring out Quidditch and House Cup points, since for example any win when there’s a player from another house would be a combination of two houses’ work.

## Gryffindor didn’t get a player from another house for the final.

Further evidence that it probably isn’t allowed is that when Harry ends up in the hospital wing and can’t be Seeker, no one ever brings up the idea of Gryffindor getting someone from another house to play for them. Gryffindor was a player short, and desperately needed another one to have any chance of not getting thoroughly beaten. Oliver Wood definitely wanted to win, and, however he would have felt about the idea of a non-Gryffindor on the team in general, would have been glad to accept a player from *anywhere*, including another house, in that circumstance if it was allowed.

> “Now, listen here, you lot,’ he said, glowering at them all, ‘we should have won the Quidditch Cup last year. We’re easily the best team. But unfortunately, owing to circumstances beyond our control …’
>
> Harry shifted guiltily in his seat. He had been unconscious in the hospital wing for the final match of the previous year, meaning that Gryffindor had been a player short and had suffered their worst defeat in three hundred years.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 7 (Mudbloods and Murmurs)*</sup></sub>

In addition, the students from both Hufflepuff and Ravenclaw were very eager to see Slytherin lose the House Cup, so would gladly help Gryffindor if it meant Slytherin would end up losing.

> “Which means,’ Dumbledore called over the storm of applause, for even Ravenclaw and Hufflepuff were celebrating the downfall of Slytherin, ‘we need a little change of decoration.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 17 (The Man with Two Faces)*</sup></sub>

Professor McGonagall was also somewhat willing to bend the rules if it meant Slytherin would lose, since she got Harry on the Gryffindor team. If there was any way to allow someone from another house to play on their team in the final match when Harry couldn’t, she’d probably be willing to allow it so Gryffindor wouldn’t be so thoroughly beaten in both the Quidditch and House Cup.

> “I shall speak to Professor Dumbledore and see if we can’t bend the first-year rule. Heaven knows, we need a better team than last year. *Flattened* in that last match by Slytherin, I couldn’t look Severus Snape in the face for weeks …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 9 (The Midnight Duel)*</sup></sub>

Oliver Wood also knew how much McGonagall wanted their team to win as well, so would likely at least try to get her to let someone from another house play for them in the final as an emergency situation substitute if he thought it was possible that she could allow it.

> “I know,’ said Harry, ‘but McGonagall still wants to strip it down –’
>
> Wood went pale.
> ‘I’ll go and talk to her, Harry,’ he promised. ‘I’ll make her see reason … a Firebolt … a real Firebolt, on our team … she wants Gryffindor to win as much as we do … I’ll make her see sense … a *Firebolt* …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 12 (The Patronus)*</sup></sub>

If no one from another house played on the Gryffindor team *then*, it’s probably not allowed at all.

Comment: You should make bold the **for their house** (the actual quote in the book) to really help it stand out, maybe? Also maybe you could add something about how upset Hufflepuff/Ravenclaw were at Gryffindor for losing points simply because it meant they wouldn't win over Slytherin! That shows just how much enmity there was between certain houses. You pointed out the cheating part of different houses but I would say that even if no cheating was involved it would still cause a Quidditch Cup (and maybe House Cup?) problem simply by having more than one house on the same house team.

Comment: The example of McLaggen is interesting. If he was *sooooooo* keen to play - as evidently he was - why not try out for another house team if he could

Comment: @Pryftan Thanks a lot, your suggestions were all good so I’ve edited my answer to add them all in! :) Overall, I think Hogwarts wouldn’t allow students to play for another house’s team since allowing that would make things more complicated in various ways, including ones difficult to ‘fix’ or control for. I can’t imagine that there’s any situation that would make the Hogwarts staff want to choose to allow it - though Quidditch is a popular sport and many students want to play, it doesn’t seem worth it to allow other house members on house-specific teams, especially considering point awarding.

Comment: @Miss Bella True. And I just remembered something else too: Even the heads of houses have a rivalry going don't they? You cite this but it also goes for the House Cup; another example McGonagall gives not just the Gryffindors points (who were at 0) at end of OotP but also Luna points for Ravenclaw (after the battle of the Death Eaters - most powerful of which would be you - and the kids) right as Severus was trying to take points away (and it was already at 0). And there are I'm sure many other examples. Anyway good updates!

Comment: @Pryftan Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @Pryftan That’s true, the Heads of House do have a rivalry going which extended to both the Quidditch and House Cups. Even Dumbledore, the headmaster, was biased a bit towards his own house and wanted them to succeed in the Hogwarts competitions. Also interesting about the example you cite is how McGonagall gives Luna points more grudgingly than the Gryffindors, ‘50 points for Ravenclaw, I suppose’. Thanks also for recognizing my power!! :D I’m glad you like my updates, thanks! :)

Comment: @Pryftan Sorry it’s taken so long to get one comment right!

Comment: @Miss Bella Ha! You admit it you're not perfect. And by extension the Dark Lord is not perfect either since as you proudly (and I think quite understandably too!) proclaim he taught you personally! (But otherwise known as: we're all human and imperfect and you got it right in the end)

Comment: @Pryftan Indeed, I’m not perfect, my attempt to retrieve the prophecy proved that. The Dark Lord, however, is another matter! He taught me very well! Though, he’d have been wise to trust Snape less... (Thanks a lot, I hopefully won’t do that again.)

Comment: @Miss Bella You know I embody a lot of Severus Snape... either way - Severus was truly amazing - as was your master's foe Dumbledore (as Severus wisely told you). Even so I don't see how Severus couldn't have not fooled him. As for the prophecy there are a couple ways of looking at that: (1) you were too rash as was your wan; (2) Harry is a right brat and so he ruined the plot (but you got revenge in another way - albeit crueller way) once again (the fact your Lord also has been foiled by Harry many times might make it less an issue for you the servant?). Both; have to stop due to website!

Answer (score 19):

J.K. Rowling didn't mention if it was against the rule simply because there was no need for it.

Quidditch is just like a normal school sport where different houses compete with each other. **Houses are the teams** and if one wants to play, it should be through their own house.

Comment: Although minimalist, I think this is a good answer.  Harry Potter's house system is not a new invention - it's directly based on the British boarding-school system.  I wouldn't be surprised if this hadn't really _occurred_ to Rowling, much like it hadn't occurred to me (as somebody who went to boarding school and competed in inter-house sports and competition, despite having friends in other houses).

Comment: In the British public school system, it's not inconceivable that a House team, depleted by circumstances beyond their control (maybe an outbreak of food poisoning confined to that House) might be loaned players from other Houses so that an important match could go ahead.  The loaned players would, of course, consider it a point of honour to play to their full capacity.  But this is a fanciful possibility. You play for YOUR House team.

Comment: Saharsh, what are these houses you mention? HP Houses? Some other houses that exist in real-life? When you say «Quidditch is just like a normal school sport where different houses compete with each other.», I don't recognize this reality and don't understand what your answer is. Your answer would be improved if you explained what these "different houses" are, and how "houses are the teams". It seems obvious and self-evident to you, but for me it is not.

Comment: @ANeves (Some) real world schools have houses just like Hogwarts has houses. As mentioned in the comments above, the house system isn't something JKR came up with. In the real world, the whole point of a house team is that it is made up entirely of members of the house. Which really makes sense right? Otherwise it's hardly a house team. That's how it is in real schools and we can assume that's how it is at Hogwarts. Partly by the same logic. How can it be the Slytherin Quidditch team if the Keeper's a Ravenclaw. Also because the house system wasn't JKR's invention.

Comment: Since she hasn't said actually stated that Hogwarts houses are different in this respect, it makes sense to assume that, in this way, Hogwarts house teams work in the same way house teams work in real life. In the same way that we just assume Hogwarts homework needs to be turned in on time and there's no need to state that Hogwarts homework is the same as Muggle homework and you won't be able to get away with not doing it if you Transfigure your unfinished homework into a suitably impressive spaniel :P

Comment: @ANeves so the point is that if you use something that also exists in real life, of course you have to state explicitly the ways in which that thing works differently in your world (for example, in JKR's world, you get assigned to a house by a magical hat which can see inside your head). Otherwise it can be assumed that in your world it works in the same way the reader is familiar with

Comment: @LaurencePayne And there might not even be rules saying you cannot play for another house's team, just tradition.  Tradition, of course, being stronger than rules.

Comment: @ANeves Here is more if you want to know about the School House System (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_system). It isn't something that the author really came up with. It exists in British schools and British colonial countries (like India) as well. So, if I am speaking of Houses, I mean both HP world and actual world. Speaking of teams and competition, there is a paragraph in the same Wikipedia page with heading **Competition Between Houses** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_system#Competition_between_houses). Very first line mentions the competitive sports matches.

Comment: @LaurencePayne my first hand experience of the system would be that the house would simply not compete in the game under those circumstances. I remember such a situation occurring where my house decided not to field a team simply because we were all rubbish at the sport. Then again they also made me compete in the hurdles so common sense does not always reign supreme.

Comment: Note that the house system is not confined to public (meaning high status private schools) schools, or to boarding schools in Britain.  Both my secondary schools were state day schools, and had houses.

Comment: @Au101 and Saharsh, I understand, thank you; but my point still stands, that that explanation is not obvious for non-English, non-Indian, or non-US people, and it should be included in the answer.

Comment: @ANeves I'm curious what makes you believe those who aren't English, not Indian and not US people would feel the statement isn't obvious? Either there is a real miscommunication here or I am imagining a very different statement you're thinking of (which of course is a miscommunication in a way).